# deploy script warning, likely error

Tags: truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

```
var CredentialOrgFactory = artifacts.require("CredentialOrgFactory");
var CredentialFactory = artifacts.require("CredentialFactory");
var ApplicantFactory = artifacts.require("ApplicantFactory");
//var ProcessCredentials = artifacts.require("ProcessCredentials");

module.exports = async(deployer) => {
    let deployCredentialOrgFactory = await deployer.deploy(CredentialOrgFactory);
    let deployCredentialFactory = await deployer.deploy(CredentialFactory);
    contractCredentialFactory = await CredentialFactory.deployed()
    let setAddress = await contractTwo.setAddress(
        CredentialOrgFactory.address,
        { gas: 200000 }
    );
};
```

with the message:

(node:13120) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
//some unimportant stuff  //
(node:13120) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13120) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

what is the proper coding in the 2_deploy_contracts.js file?   maybe i'm not setting the address of CredentialFactory properly?  thoughts?  i'm a bit stuck atm.

it could be part of the test file.
    pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

```
import "truffle/Assert.sol";  
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";  
import "../contracts/CredentialFactory.sol";  

contract TestCredentialFactory {  
CredentialFactory credentialFactory = CredentialFactory(DeployedAddresses.CredentialFactory());  


    function testIsActiveValid() public {  
        bool r = credentialFactory.isCredentialActive(0x2259aA88Cc0aa3d83d5ec5aF6096C627778FBD06, 0);  
        Assert.isTrue(r, "Valid isActive Test.");  
    }  

    function testIsActiveInvalid() public {  
        bool r = credentialFactory.isCredentialActive(0x5a186B7FeC36909678211F69beB67EC3b1E4fFBB, 5);  
        Assert.isFalse(r, "Outside Range IsActive Test");  
    }  
    function SelectOrgCredentialCount() public {  
        uint256 testVal = uint256(credentialFactory.SelectOrgCredentialCount(0x2259aA88Cc0aa3d83d5ec5aF6096C627778FBD06));  
        uint256 expected = 1;  
        Assert.equal(testVal, expected, "Expected Credential Count (1)");  
    }  

}
```

Comment: Async/await are not supported in deployment scripts, see comment from developers https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/501#issuecomment-332589663

Comment: Thanks, working on it now, came across another issue, maybe you would be willing to try your hand at this  [problem](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/56272/contract-compiles-and-fails-to-deploy-on-remix-or-local)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This layout clears things up and allows the waits to happen.

```
var CredentialOrgFactory = artifacts.require("CredentialOrgFactory");  
var CredentialFactory = artifacts.require("CredentialFactory");  
var ApplicantFactory = artifacts.require("ApplicantFactory");  
//var ProcessApplicants = artifacts.require("ProcessApplicants");  

module.exports = async function(deployer, accounts) {  
    let aInst, bInst, cInst, dInst;
    let aAccount;

await Promise.all([
  deployer.deploy(CredentialOrgFactory),
  deployer.deploy(CredentialFactory),
  deployer.deploy(ApplicantFactory)
  // deployer.deploy(ProcessApplicants)
]);

instances = await Promise.all([
  CredentialOrgFactory.deployed(),
  CredentialFactory.deployed(),
  ApplicantFactory.deployed()
  //ProcessApplicants.deployed()
])

aInst = instances[0];
bInst = instances[1];
cInst = instances[2];
//dInst = instances[3];

results = await Promise.all([
  bInst.setAddress(aInst.address),
  cInst.setAddress(aInst.address),
  //dInst.setAddress(aInst.address, bInst.address, cInst.address)
]);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your specific question, but it could resolve it:

Currently I am using this library: https://github.com/LimeChain/etherlime
to deploy contracts it works with async/await and has a nice reporting at the end of each deploy. Currently it even support testing like truffle's. It is a bit more stable and predictable with using ethersjs under the hood than the web3js.

Comment: thanks for the answer, is a course project, and so can't use that.