# contract compiles and fails to deploy on Remix or local

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment

[GitHub File Link](https://github.com/shaddow1201/CredentialVerify/blob/master/contracts/CredentialFactory.sol)

I can compile and deploy CredentialOrgFactory, and compile CredentialFactory but not deploy

```
REMIX error:   
    creation of CredentialFactory pending...  
    [vm]from:0xca3...a733cto:CredentialFactory.(constructor)value:0 wei data:0x608...a0029logs:0hash:0xcbc...d4427  
    Debug  
 status     0x0 Transaction mined but execution failed transaction hash     0xcbcb460efa2e16890b55d82058b4a152213fc1b38c719f389b57b9b3e81d4427  
 contract address   0x5e72914535f202659083db3a02c984188fa26e9f  
 from   0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c  
 to     CredentialFactory.(constructor)  
 gas    3000000 gas  

 transaction cost   927345 gas   
 execution cost     35597 gas   
 hash   0xcbcb460efa2e16890b55d82058b4a152213fc1b38c719f389b57b9b3e81d4427  
 input  0x608...a0029  
 decoded input  {}  
 decoded output      -   
 logs   []  
 value  0 wei  

VM error: revert.  
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.  
Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.  Debug the transaction to get more information.  

the truffle error on migrate:
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js  
  Deploying CredentialOrgFactory...  
  ... 0xc044d4c153739733aedc33dcb41b66de989e4451b41011b14aae69a8070119a9  
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.  
Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.  

Config:  
    module.exports = {  
      // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>  
      // for more about customizing your Truffle configuration!  
      networks: {  
        development: {  
          host: "127.0.0.1",  
          port: 8545,  
          network_id: "*" // Match any network id  
        }  
      }  
};

Deploy file:  
var CredentialOrgFactory = artifacts.require("CredentialOrgFactory");  
var CredentialFactory = artifacts.require("CredentialFactory");  
var ApplicantFactory = artifacts.require("ApplicantFactory"); 
module.exports = async function(deployer) {  
    let aInst, bInst;  

    await Promise.all([  
      deployer.deploy(CredentialOrgFactory),  
      deployer.deploy(CredentialFactory)  
    ]);  

    instances = await Promise.all([  
        CredentialOrgFactory.deployed(),  
        CredentialFactory.deployed()  
    ])  

    aInst = instances[0];  
    bInst = instances[1];  

    results = await Promise.all([  
      bInst.setAddress(aInst.address)  
    ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely failing during the deployment in the execution of your constructor.

Within the constructor, you call:

```
createCredential("A", "Associate Degree in Basket Weaving", "BA - Arts");
```

This ends up running:

```
CredentialOrgFactory cof = CredentialOrgFactory(credentialOrgContractAddress);
if (cof.isCredentialOrg(msg.sender)){
```

At this point, `credentialOrgContractAddress` has not been initialized. It is the default value of `0x0`. When you try to call the `isCredentialOrg()` method on it, you're actually invoking it on the zero address, which would result in a revert since that's not actually a contract.

Comment: Thank you!  I KNEW it was something i was MISSING in the 'flow'.

Comment: that was it, appreciate!